# Configuring results from STCentroid select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to configure the results from a STCentroid select statement?

If I run a select statement at the minute, I will get overly precise responses 
     i.e. POINT (399419.42500005924 90290.17500002397)
I just need to grab the numbers before the decimal, I don't need the detail provided.

Answer (score 4):

You could extract the coordiantes and round these values:

```
Select ROUND(SP_GEOMETRY.STX, 0) As X, ROUND(SP_GEOMETRY.STY, 0) As Y
   From dbo.MY_TABLE;
```

And you can extend this so that the result is returned as a POINT:

```
Select 'POINT(' 
      + Cast(ROUND(SP_GEOMETRY.STX, 0) As VarChar) 
      + ' ' 
      + Cast(ROUND(SP_GEOMETRY.STY, 0) As VarChar)
      + ')' As WKT
   From dbo.MY_TABLE;
```

where SP_GEOMETRY is the name of the column holding your spatial data

Comment: Hi Peter I had thought about this, but I didn't want to split this out into holding tables, I did find a different solution which I will post below.

Comment: Hi Steve, well my suggestion can by used like yours. You don't need to create a new table, you can just add the 'POINT...)' to you select statement

Answer (score 1):

I kind of answered my own question by grabbing the relevant parts of the geometry that make up the X and Y of my record:

```
cast(SUBSTRING(M.GEOMETRY.STCentroid().ToString(),8,6)as int) AS EASTING
```

This grabs the for me the Easting and the following grabs the Northing for me:

```
cast(SUBSTRING(M.GEOMETRY.STCentroid().ToString(),CHARINDEX(' ',M.GEOMETRY.STCentroid().ToString(),1+CHARINDEX(' ',M.GEOMETRY.STCentroid().ToString(),0)),6)as int) AS NORTHING
```

This enables me to create my Easting and Northing Column at the same time as the other relevant information in my query, without having to have a temporary holding table.

Comment: Also a possible workaround. Not that different from my suggestion in other ways than that you are modifying the string and I'm modifying the numerical value. Or am  missing something?